# Bug with question titles containing $ (dollar sign)

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, title

Titles that include `$_` appear in the question list improperly.

For an example, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+replace+characters) search, and scroll about halfway down looking for the title "can I get PHP to stop replacing..."

The title appears as:

> can I get PHP to stop replacing ‘.’
>   characters in can I get PHP to stop
>   replacing ‘.’ characters in $_GET or
>   $_POST arrays ?GET or can I get PHP to
>   stop replacing ‘.’ characters in $_GET
>   or $_POST arrays ?POST arrays ?

However the actual title is actually:

> can I get PHP to stop replacing ‘.’
>   characters in $_GET or $_POST arrays ?

Comment: Seems like `$_` is used to insert the title, so the title is reinserted for every occurrence.

Comment: Looks like something wasn't escaped quite right...

Comment: Appears to be fixed now :)

Comment: Belongs on careers.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answering this to accept the answer ;)

The issue is fixed.

Comment: excellent work! :)